# Can the full and reduced group $C^*$-algebras be "noncanonically" isomorphic?

Tags: gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, amenability

Is there a  locally  compact group $G$ such that the canonical map from $C^{*}(G)$  to  $C^{*}_{red} G$  is  not  isomorphism, hence $G$ is not amenable but these two $C^{*}$  algebras  are isomorphic $C^{*}$ algebras via  another morphism?

Comment: It is known that if $C^*(G)$ and $C^*_r(G)$ are isomorphic (through any *-isomorphism) then $G$ is amenable (and vice-versa of course). This should be no surprise I think, as C*-algebras are quite rigid because of the C*-identity and hence the existence of a unique C*-norm on a C*-algebra.

Comment: @Phoenix87 Can you provide a reference? (Alain Valette has already given a justification.)

Comment: @Phoneix87 Moreover, I would argue that not all isomorphism questions about Cstar algebras are "intuitively" clear - I do not know of an "easy" proof that the reduced Cstar algebras of $F_2$ and $F_3$ are non-isomorphic, for instance. Also $C^*(G)\cong C^*(H)$ whenever $G$ and $H$ are finite abelian groups of the same cardinality...

Comment: @YemonChoi please reread my comment carefully. I've never said they are intuitive, but that it shouldn't be surprising. As for a reference there must be something in Brown-Ozawa (although just for the discrete case), but I can't check as I don't have a copy of it with me right now. There is a mention to this fact at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_algebra#The_reduced_group_C.2A-algebra_Cr.2A.28G.29, although there is no reference cited there

Comment: @Phoenix87 I appreciate your point, and I have read your comments, but I think "This should be no surprise I think, as $C^*$-algebras are quite rigid" is not very solid reasoning. I agree that the statement sounds _plausible_, but many things sound _plausible_ in mathematics without being true.

Comment: @YemonChoi  thank you very much for your revision of the title of the question.

Comment: For the interest of those reading: in general $C_r^*(G)$ does not even "remember" if $G$ is unimodular or not: see, for instance, the remarks on page 190 of J. Rosenberg's paper _The $C^*$-algebras of some real and $p$-adic solvable gropups_, Pac. J. M. 65 (1976)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If $C^*(G)$ is isomorphic to $C^*_r(G)$, then $C^*_r(G)$ has a 1-dimensional representation, i.e. $G$ has a 1-dimensional representation $\chi$ weakly contained in the regular representation $\lambda_G$. Then $1_G=\chi\otimes\overline{\chi}$ is weakly contained in $\lambda_G\otimes\overline{\lambda_G}\simeq \infty.\lambda_G$, hence $G$ is amenable.

Comment: Prof. Valette  thank you very much for your very interesting answer.